# ML vs Math terminology

Tags: soft-question, terminology, machine-learning

I read often in machine learning the termonilogy "smooth" and "differentiable" referring to a property to commonly used activation functions. I really struggle sometimes, because for example the ReLU function is not differentiable, about the smoothness I'm really not sure either. I think in math the term "smooth" is commonly used to describe the class of differentiable functions, in other context (for example one of my references in differential geometry) they use the terminolgy "sufficiently smooth", meaning the mappings analyzed are $C^k$ differentiable, for some $k$ (commonly $2$). So to me "smooth" means we have existance of the derivatives at least to a certain order.

My question is... are both "differentiable" and "smooth" miss-used in the ML language (comparing to math terminology)?

Comment: Smooth refers to arbitrarily often differentiable such as the logistic function.

Comment: ReLU is differentiable, even in mathematics. Keywords: weak derivatives.

Comment: @CaveJohnson ReLU is not differentiable as a function but it is differentiable as a distribution (which is not a function but a functional). The way usually backpropagation is explained doesn't rely on distributions theory at all. From "Rudin Functional analysis" : *The theory of distributions frees differential calculus from certain diffi­culties  that arise because nondifferentiable functions exist*. The ReLU is one of those functions, so I disagree with that statement.

Comment: That simply depends on how you define ''differentiable'', i.e. it is just a matter of terminology. In PDE it is very customary to say weakly differentiable functions are differentiable. On the other hand, people who use BP in practice do not care about such pedantic difference in terminology, while people who do theoretical analysis in ML do not use such terminology.

Comment: I don't know what BP is. About the PDE context, I think the context is different (in terms of how the terminology is used). I don't find any ambiguity in general, if you have a differentiable function you can construct the related distribution and the derivative in the distribution sense is well defined. I'm personally not familiar of any work of "theoretical analysis in ML", I do struggle to find some analysis that make some form of sense (rigorously speaking).